# There must be simpler ways to say "again" other than 又再一次的

Tags: grammar

I'm confused by the sentence ”他又再一次的在那里找圣人”.

The sentence is from the book  **Pepper, Jeff; Wang, Xiao Hui. The Rise of the Monkey King** in which the english translation reads as:

"Again he searched for holy sages."

It seems to me there are simpler ways to write this sentence. Particularly, I find the use of “又再一次” very convoluted (why not just use 又), nor I understand what is the function of “的” in "又再一次的“.

Comment: 再度 is simpler and better than 又再一次的。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, You can use either 又 (once more) or (again) 再 in this context

- 又一次尋找 = search once more (separate from the previous search)
- 再一次尋找 = search once again (renew/ repeat a search)

又再一次尋找 = search once more/ again

putting 又 and 再 together as a compound word 又再 is for emphasis and disambiguation.

Similarly:

尋 = 找 = search

尋找 = search

As you can see, putting two characters with similar meanings together to coin a compound is a common practice

閃(flash; **dodge**)

避 (avoid; **dodge**)

閃避 = **dodge**

*As for 的 in 他又再一次的, it is used as an adverb marker (somewhat controversially)  the same as 地 . It can be omitted*

Answer (score 0):

I agree. The sentence can be simplified as:

- 他又一次的在那里找圣人. Also, 的 can be omitted, as
- 他又一次在那里找圣人. Or, simply
- 他又在那里找圣人. Since 又 already indicates he has done that before, so it makes 一次 redundant.

But, we need to read/examine the full text to justify the simplifications.